# Total an access database by quarter?

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-access

I'm looking for a way to split a large block of data in access into quarters and then total all of the data by quarter.

I know how to generate a report and have it break everything off into quarters I just am not sure how to make sure it totals each column at the end of the quarter. Right now, i'm just exporting it into excel and doing SUM formulas by hand. I'm fairly new to Access, so i'm not sure if this is possible or i'm just overlooking a simple step.

Comment: You will need to give us some idea of your data structure for this...

Comment: Format(DateField, "yyyy-q") should get you started, I'd think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured I would give an explanation of how I did this.

Out the data into Access and did a Report Wizard. I just sorted by Date, and from there did a summary by quarter. On the Summary options, I just did a SUM function for all data inside of the quarter, and from there I had a nice little report that was separated by quarter and had all the totals for each column.